# Phaser P2 System throw the ball into the net hoop

Tags: physics, phaser-framework, p2

​​​​​​​Now I start building a basket ball game that using Physics P2 system. I would like to ask you about the concept of throwing the ball to basket net. Would you mind giving me some idea for doing this?

Eg: I would like to use the method as arcade like `this.game.physics.arcade.angleToPointer` when I hover the mouse and click to throw the ball into the net hoop. Does P2 have `this.game.physics.arcade.angleToPointer` the same as Arcade system? A simple code would be appreciate bro

Comment: Here is a better place to ask your question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ . Here its kind of too broad.

Comment: Thanks you for guiding bro

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because they followed the advice of a comment and posted to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/121320 . I don't think they necessarily had to, but ... they did.